# Drag&Drop not working on first program start only

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a very weird problem. I have a Winforms application written in VS2012 for .NET Framework 4.
In the app the user can drag&drop files into a list to load them. This has always worked very well. The code for this is:

```
Private Sub dgvFiles_DragEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles lvFiles.DragEnter, lblNodFiles.DragEnter
   If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub dgvFiles_DragDrop(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles lvFiles.DragDrop, lblNodFiles.DragDrop
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        Dim DroppedFiles() As String
        DroppedFiles = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())
       'rest of file processing, not relevant
    End If
End Sub
```

As I said, this works nicely. I recently noticed however, that on the first run of the application after the installation it doesn't. The `DragEnter` event does not fire, neither does the DragDrop event. The mouse cursor stays the Drag-Not-Allowed-cursor also.

When I close the application and restart it, it works flawlessly again.

The only difference I can see is, that on the first program start the user has to register the application through a registration form that I load before the actual `Application.Run`.

```
''' <summary>
''' Main Sub
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>Handles loading of settings and so on</remarks>
Sub Main()
    'Some application event handler are set here and some irrelevant stuff
    'Update Splash Screen here
    frmSplash.UpdateText()
    frmSplash.Show()
    frmSplash.Refresh()

    'Here the registration dialog is shown where the user enters his data
    'which is confirmed and saved. Returns true if all is ok.
    Dim isRegged As Boolean = PerformRegistrationCheck(0, False)

    'Another splash update to accomodate for registration details
    frmSplash.UpdateText()
    frmSplash.Refresh()
    If isRegged Then
      'App preparation steps
      frmSplash.Close()
      Application.Run(frmMain)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit:** I tried to throw out the registration check and it still doesn't work on the first program start but without a problem afterwards.

Does someone have any suggestion or idea what could cause such a behaviour? I am completely lost.
I am happy to provide additional relevant information if need be. Code in both VB.NET or C# is welcome.

**Edit 2:** Hans has answered the question in the comments. For an installer there is a workaround that can be found at the following link. You basically tell explorer.exe to run the program you want. This will lead to the program being run with non-elevated priviliges.

http://mdb-blog.blogspot.de/2013/01/nsis-lunch-program-as-user-from-uac.html

Comment: My crystal ball says that your installer is also starting the program.  Don't do that.

Comment: You are right about that. What is the problem with that?

Comment: Your program runs with admin privileges.  Acquired by the installer when it displayed the UAC prompt.  Hard to notice, except the one thing you are asking about, a non-elevated program like Explorer cannot drag+drop into an elevated one.  UIPI stops that.  No known workaround afaik.

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant hans. If you could post this as an answer please, then I could close this question. Thank you.